# Fork bomb protection not working : Amount of processes not limited

Tags: process, ulimit, resource-limiting

I just came to realize that my system is not limiting the amount of processes per user properly thus not preventing a user from doing a fork-bomb and crashing the entire system:

```
user@thebe:~$ cat /etc/security/limits.conf | grep user
user        hard    nproc   512
user@thebe:~$ ulimit -u
1024
user@thebe:~$ :(){ :|:& };:
[1] 2559
user@thebe:~$ ht-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
...
Connection to thebe closed by remote host.
```

Is this a bug or why is it ignoring the limit in `limits.conf` and why is not applying the limit that `ulimit -n` claims it to be?

PS: I really don't think the memory limit is hit before the process limit. This machine has 8GB ram and it was using only 4% of it at the time when I dropped the fork bomb.

EDIT:

I managed to reproduce this on a live CD. So  I guess this must be a bug. It basically ends up killing all processes, including system critical things like X11, SSHD etc.

Any user can crash the system.

Comment: -n is the number of file descriptors, not processes.  You want `ulimit -u`

Comment: @psusi, thanks, but that gives the same result :s
`user@thebe:~$ ulimit -u`
`1024`

Comment: When I run `ulimit -u` I get 31325.  When I run `ulimit -u 512` it goes go 512.  When I run that fork-bomb, the rest of my system is just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that `/etc/security/limits.conf` does work, but needs reboot before it gets interpreted. A log-out is not sufficient.

I recommend to anybody to a limit to the config file like

```
user hard nproc 512
```

Replace `user` with any username that you would want to limit.

Or, better:

```
@group hard nproc 512
```

Replace `group` with any user-group that you want to limit.

Comment: Depending on software you use, even a single-user system might need more processes than 512.  If you find things mysteriously don't work after implementing this, you may need to adjust the actual number of processes you permit.